# To display "total" (sum ) of each row using DAX in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following format of data :

```
Machine Name | Error_code_a | Error_code_b | Error_code_c | Error_code_d 
MA01         |   0          |  1           |     0        | 0
MA02         |   1          |  0           |     1        | 0
MA02         |   1          |  1           |     1        | 0
```

Where `0` and `1` simply represents if an error code is present or absent.

I need one column where the `TOTAL` or `SUM` is displayed.

Example for `MA01`, the sum column should show `1` , for `MA02` it should show `2` (since 1+1).

I am able to do this column wise, but need some DAX query for doing it row wise.

Answer (score 1):

so turns out it was pretty straight forward! 
We need to create a new column / custom column / measure and then : MySum = [error_code_a] + [error_code_b] + [error_code_c] + so on and you will get a new column which is basically summing up each row!